# PlantUML diagram for an Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, plantuml

Trying to have an overall diagram for my eclipse java project, not sure how to.

I have PlantUML installed but it only shows a diagram for each individual class can't find any information on generating an overall diagram.

Need help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Then, present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get.

Answer (score 2):

### To use PlantUml

1. (install the Plugin in Eclipse)

#### for a class (simple case)

1. **Open the `PlantUml View` in Eclipse**
2. **Click** on a Java class (.java file, in `Project Explorer`) - make sure you have the `Link with Editor` on
3. Wait for the Diagram to be generated in the `PlantUml View`

[image]

#### for a single package

1. Click on a Package (instead of a class)

[image]

#### for the whole project (/multiple packages)

1. Open the **`PlantUml Project Class Diagram View`**
2. Enable the option in `PlantUml > Project Class Diagram View > Generate packages`
3. Select & **Drag** your packages into the view

[image]
[image]

#### misc

- the official website https://plantuml.com/
- (I did this long time before, Idk where I saw the instructions, in the Official website / some posts, but now I cant find any...)

Answer (score 1):

I do not use PlantUML as a eclipse plugin. But the plugin description describes that the feature to generating a diagram for all Java classes is experimental. Maybe that feature doesn't work properly.

I use PlantUML as a "standalone" version in other editors. And for that i have to download and define [graph viz](https://graphviz.org/).

Maybe this site helps you: http://plantuml.com/de/graphviz-dot